# Bootstrap 4 collapse, close all other collapsible items

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using [Bootstrap 4 Collapse component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/).

When I click on *Categories*, the corresponding collapsible section should display. If I then click on *Brands*, I want the *Categories* section to collapse before the *Brands* one shows (or vice-versa).

Here the collapse *works* but multiple collapsible elements can be seen at the same time:

```css
.view-custom-filters {
  display: flex;
}

.view-collapse-button {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="#viewCustomFilters" class="view-custom-filters">
  <div class="view-collapse-wrap">
    <div class="view-collapse-button" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#categories-collapsed" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="categories-collapsed">
      Categories
    </div>
    <div class="view-collapse-content collapse" id="categories-collapsed">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <strong>All</strong>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-collapse-wrap">
    <div class="view-collapse-button" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#brands-collapsed" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="brands-collapsed">
      Brands
    </div>
    <div class="view-collapse-content collapse" id="brands-collapsed">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <strong>All</strong>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 6</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 7</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 8</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I read that to achieve what I want, I need a wrapper element and use `data-parent` on the `.collapse` elements but when doing so, I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null`.

```css
.view-custom-filters {
  display: flex;
}

.view-collapse-button {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="#viewCustomFilters" class="view-custom-filters">
  <div class="view-collapse-wrap">
    <div class="view-collapse-button" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#categories-collapsed" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="categories-collapsed">
      Categories
    </div>
    <div class="view-collapse-content collapse" id="categories-collapsed" data-parent="#viewCustomFilters">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <strong>All</strong>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-collapse-wrap">
    <div class="view-collapse-button" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#brands-collapsed" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="brands-collapsed">
      Brands
    </div>
    <div class="view-collapse-content collapse" id="brands-collapsed" data-parent="#viewCustomFilters">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <strong>All</strong>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 6</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 7</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 8</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

How can I achieve to have only 1 collapsible element shown at a time?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You were almost there.

You own error is you add a `#` into `id` of `viewCustomFilters` so `<div id="#viewCustomFilters" class="view-custom-filters">` instead was `<div id="viewCustomFilters" class="view-custom-filters">`

```css
.view-custom-filters {
  display: flex;
}

.view-collapse-button {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="viewCustomFilters" class="view-custom-filters">
  <div class="view-collapse-wrap">
    <div class="view-collapse-button" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#categories-collapsed" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="categories-collapsed">
      Categories
    </div>
    <div class="view-collapse-content collapse" id="categories-collapsed" data-parent="#viewCustomFilters">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <strong>All</strong>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-collapse-wrap">
    <div class="view-collapse-button" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#brands-collapsed" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="brands-collapsed">
      Brands
    </div>
    <div class="view-collapse-content collapse" id="brands-collapsed" data-parent="#viewCustomFilters">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <strong>All</strong>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 6</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 7</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 8</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Oh stupid man! That was worse than what I thought. Seems I forgot how to write HTML :) Thanks for spotting the issue!

Comment: No problem :) .